# Error connecting to a PostgreSQL database from QGIS using SSL certificates

Tags: qgis, postgis, postgresql, ssl

I'm trying to connect QGIS (v3.14) to a PostgreSQL database hosted on Google Cloud.  I've successfully connected to the database through pgAdmin (v4.23) so my assumption is that there isn't a problem with the database itself, more likely a QGIS related issue.

I have also successfully connected to another PostgreSQL database that doesn't use SSL authentication, just a username and password.  So I suspect its related to the certificates / key and username / password combination.

[image: i've added an image of the connection error message - blanked out IP and password]

[image: also added an image of the DB connection properties dialogue]

[image: and an image of the authentication methods i've tried].

The only other things I can think of are 1. there isn't a `root.crt` file (do I need one if I already have the certificate and key specified / referenced elsewhere?) or 2. maybe I need to make a change to the the `pg_hba.conf` (it currently just contains the standard info).

I couldn't find anything else on here that specifically answered the problem, but if I've missed it please point me to the link.

Comment: had to use verify-full for SSL aws postgis connection, not sure if that applies to your google cloud service.

Comment: Thank you @Mapperz I'm looking that option with a software colleague

Comment: Did you find the answer? I'm having the same problem